# Peer closed connection in SSL handshake

Tags: nginx, proxy, ssl, reverse-proxy, handshake

I have a question about nginx. I created a reverse proxy by nginx. Activated SSL encryption with Letsencrypt. All is ok and all requests from client are sent to origin server specified in upstream. Sometimes I have error

> 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.16.1 in chrome browser.

Checked nginx error.log and this is the error:

> peer closed connection in SSL handshake 104: Connection reset by peer while SSL handshaking to upstream.

I searched and tested all suggestions. Still sometimes this error occurs.

example.com.conf:

```
upstream example_com {
      server 50.90.20.70:443 max_fails=10 fail_timeout=60s;
}



server {
 server_name *.example_com;
      location / {
                  #proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                  proxy_pass https://example_com ;
                  proxy_next_upstream         error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

                  proxy_set_header         Accept-Encoding   "";
                  proxy_set_header         Host       "example.com";
                  proxy_set_header         X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header         X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                  proxy_set_header         X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                  add_header         Front-End-Https   on;
                  add_header          'host' "$host";
                  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
                  proxy_redirect        off;
                  proxy_buffering         on;
                  proxy_cache             off;
                  proxy_cache_valid         200  4h;
                  proxy_cache_use_stale         error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                  #proxy_ssl_verify        on;
                  #proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
                  proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                  proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
      }
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    #ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1:prime256v1;
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404;
}
```

nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  6;
worker_rlimit_nofile 5000;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
        worker_connections 1000;
        multi_accept on;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
      proxy_cache_path  /etc/nginx/cache  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC:10m
      inactive=1h  max_size=950g;
    log_format  main  '$host'

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        off;
    tcp_nopush     on;

 #server_names_hash_max_size: 512;
 server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
 keepalive_timeout  65;
 large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
 client_max_body_size 100M;
 proxy_no_cache $cookie_nocache  $arg_nocache$arg_comment $http_x_no_cache;
 proxy_no_cache $http_pragma     $http_authorization;
 proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache $arg_comment;
 proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization  $http_x_no_cache ;
 proxy_ssl_server_name on;

  #gzip  on;
  gzip on;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_min_length 256;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_types
    text/xml application/xml application/atom+xml application/rss+xml applicati$
    text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
    text/x-json application/json application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    text/css text/plain text/x-component
    font/opentype application/x-font-ttf application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    image/x-icon;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

#   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
   error_page 500 502 503 504 /error503.html;
   location = /error503.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;

        }

    }
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

Comment: *"I searched and tested all suggestions"* - which says absolutely nothing on what you actually did, i.e. the information contained in this phrase is practically zero. If the error only happens from time to time it might be some load problem on the upstream or maybe the upstream just got reconfigured or maybe .... . Note that it is the upstream which is closing the connection so the problem is there. But since there is absolutely nothing known about your upstream one could only speculate a lot.